# How can I create a generic pagined search method in NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I have several grid interfaces with some search/fitler functionality... The number of filter is 'randon' ...

Example, in my Color UI I have just onde filter: **Name** ... And my method of paging/search is :

```
public IEnumerable<Color> Search(string nameSearch, string order, int pageSize, int pageIndex, bool ascending, out int totalCount)
{
    var query = Session.QueryOver<Color>();
    var rowCountQuery = query.ToRowCountQuery();

    query.Where(color => color.Name.IsLike(nameSearch, MatchMode.Anywhere));

     if (ascending)
         query.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc();
     else
         query.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Desc();

     query.Take(__pageSize).Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize)
         .Future();

     totalCount = rowCountQuery.FutureValue<int>().Value;

     return query.List();
}
```

It´s working fine so far... But I have other several UI with same functionality and I´d like to create a generic serach function...
Is there any like that already implemented?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's with all the underscores?

Comment: Just convention : Parameter = __ , local method variable _

Comment: And let me guess, static readonly field is ______?

Comment: You should call `ToRowCountQuery()` **after** you build the where clause...or did you want the total count regardless of the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to think about creating an object to hold the the paging parameters and also validating the order column, but you could create a simple paging function like this...

```
public IEnumerable<Color> Search(string nameSearch, string order, int pageSize, int pageIndex, bool ascending, out int totalCount)
{
    var query = Session.QueryOver<Color>();

    query.Where(color => color.Name.IsLike(nameSearch, MatchMode.Anywhere));

    return Page(query, order, pageSize, pageIndex, ascending, out totalCount);
}

public IEnumerable<T> Page<T>(IQueryOver<T,T> query, string order, int pageSize, int pageIndex, bool ascending, out int totalCount)
{
     var rowCountQuery = query.ToRowCountQuery();

     query.UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(new Order(order, ascending));

     query.Take(pageSize).Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize)
         .Future();

     totalCount = rowCountQuery.FutureValue<int>().Value;

    return query.List();
}
```